# Equivalent to $modx->getDocument in YAMS

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I am converting an old mono-lingual site to a multi-lingual site with YAMS. I have a snippet including articles based on ID

```
$doc = $modx->getDocument($fromId, '*', 1); // Search published first.
```

Is there equivalent using YAMS? Like this where the language is based on current article?

```
$doc $modx-yamsGetDocument($fromId, '*', 1);
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with YAMS, but it looks like you need to run the YAMS snippet from within your code.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$result = $modx->runSnippet('YAMS', array(
    'docid' => $fromId,
    // other parameters here
));
```

Consult the YAMS [snippet documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/evo/yams/yams-english-documentation/yams-snippet) for a list of parameters to include.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I made it work.

Comment: I would like to know more about how did you end up fixing it, when I try that aproach I just get a JSON array with id's of the document, but not the value.

Comment: You need some other params as well, this is what I end up using: $doc = $modx->runSnippet('YAMS', array(
        'get' => 'data',
        'from' => 'content',
        'docid' => $fromId
    ));

Answer (score 1):

I did this workaround, hope it helps somebody:

If you manage to bring the id of the language you could do this call:

```
$modx->runSnippet("getField", array('docid'=>$id_of_the_document,'field' =>'pagetitle_'.$lang));
```

Comment: Get the language with this: $yams = YAMS::GetInstance();
$langId = $yams->GetCurrentLangId();